# Sort NSMutableArray with custom objects by another NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have 2 `NSMutableArrays`. First array contains custom object intances with property `NSString  *itemID`, second array contains only from `NSString` objects with same values of `itemID`, but in another order. I need to sort first array by `itemID` property of each object, and it should be sorted like second array.

How I can do this?

Comment: array is short, based on one key ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it/805589#805589

Comment: I've seen this solution, and it's not suitable for my question

Comment: but good question ---- >+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
guideArray = < YOUR SECOND ARRAY WITH STRING OBJECT >;    
unsortedArray = < YOUR FIRST ARRAY WITH CUSTOM OBJECT >;

[unsortedArray sortUsingComparator:^(id o1, id o2) {
    Items *item1 = o1;
    Items *item2 = o2;
    NSInteger idx1 = [guideArray indexOfObject:item1.ItemID];
    NSInteger idx2 = [guideArray indexOfObject:item2.ItemID];
    return idx1 - idx2;
}];
NSLog(@"%@",unsortedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the custom objects in an dictionary with `itemID` as key, use this dictionary as lookup to sort the objects:

```
    NSArray *objects; // your objects
    NSMutableArray *hintArray; // your sorted IDs
    NSMutableDictionary *lookupDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[objects count]];
    NSMutableArray *sortedObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[hintArray count]];

    for (id object in objects) {
        [lookupDict setValue:object forKey:[object itemID]];
    }

    for (id hint in hintArray) {
        [sortedObjects addObject:[lookupDict valueForKey:hint]];
    }
```

EDIT:
Solution with inplace sort of `objects`:

```
    NSMutableArray *objects;
    NSMutableArray *hintArray;
    NSMutableDictionary *lookupDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[hintArray count]];

    int i = 0;
    for (NSString *itemID in hintArray) {
        [lookupDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:itemID];
        i++;
    }

    [objects sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [[lookupDict valueForKey:[obj1 itemID]] compare:[lookupDict valueForKey:[obj2 itemID]]];
    }];
```

Comment: NSDictionary adds not to end of the list. So it wouldn't help

Comment: I dont get your comment. I simple build lookup dictionaries to avoid searching for each item in the sorted id-list, which will become very expensive when you got a large amount of items.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare your two objects using following syntax :-

```
[items sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Attribute *obj1, Attribute *obj2) 
{
    return [[NSNumber numberWithInt:[stringOrder indexOfObject:obj1.itemID]] compare:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[stringOrder indexOfObject:obj2.itemID]]]
}];
```

or else you can use following snippet :

```
NSArray* sortedKeys = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2)
 {
    return [obj1 compareTo:obj2];
 }
```

Enjoy Programming !

Comment: Thanks, this is also working answer