# Sort array using order in other array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sorting

I have `NSArray` of custom objects with id property and an another `NSArray` of `NSString`. The second array is a list of ids. So I want to get array of object arranged by order in second array.

Comment: You've created a custom object with a `@property ... id`?  Sounds like a bad idea in Objective-C.  Anyway, what have you tried?

Comment: @trojanfoe, it should be any other property, for example, name. I have a list of names and i want to arrange a list of objects with order of list of names.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/15944419/1187415 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/16518619/1187415.

Answer (score 3):

use an NSSortDescriptor, or sort with a block that performs the comparison in the other array.

[How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Update:

Since neither the objects nor the list of ids have a reference to the other, there is no efficient way to reorder. Without introducing a new collection, you will have to iterate through one of the lists many many times.

The only way you can do this efficiently is to change your architecture and use a hash map of some kind such as an NSDictionary so you can quickly reference an object from the id. Alternatively you can use an [ordered dictionary](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html).

Comment: I saw this question. But this methods compare objects in array to be sorted. I want to arrange objects by order in external array. I'm afraid of running throw all the items

Comment: I can't think of a straight forward way to efficiently reorder them unless you put your objects into an NSDictionary keyed by their id. Then create a new array by looping through your array of ids, grab the object from the hashtable and push it into the new array.

Comment: yes, I don't see any pretty solution, that's why I've asked a question here